# How to replace all occurrences of a string except the first one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string

I have this string:

```
hello world hello world hello world hello
```

and I need to get the following:

```
hello world hello hello hello
```

If I use:

```
str = str.replace('world', '');
```

it only removes the first occurrence of `world` in the above string.

How can I replace all the occurrences of it except the first one?

Comment: @Legman That is not an accurate duplicate. The OP isn't asking about all instances.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass a function to [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), where you can specify to omit replacing the first occurrence. Also make your first parameter of *replace* a regex to match all occurrences.

**Demo**

```js
let str = 'hello world hello world hello world hello',
    i = 0;
    
str = str.replace(/world/g, m  => !i++ ? m : '');
console.log(str);
```

**Note**

You could avoid using the global counter variable `i` by using a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
let str = 'hello world hello world hello world hello';

str = str.replace(/world/g, (i => m => !i++ ? m : '')(0));
console.log(str);
```

Comment: You don't need to use regex for simple cases as in the question, you can match a string with `replaceAll`:  `str.replaceAll('world', m  => !i++ ? m : '');`

Comment: just bear in mind that replaceAll is not nativelly supported in nodeJS version < 15. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

Comment: That's true. For future readers: you can use `replaceAll` in some situations and add a polyfill if needed, as I stated in that answer: [Jest: TypeError: replaceAll is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67877325/8839059)

Answer (score 2):

To provide an alternative to @Kristianmitk excellent answer, we can use a positive lookbehind, which is supported in [Node.Js](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions) & Chrome >= 62

```js
const string = 'hello world hello world hello world hello';

console.log(
  string.replace(/(?<=world[\s\S]+)world/g, '')
);
// or
console.log(
  string.replace(/(?<=(world)[\s\S]+)\1/g, '')
);
```

---

Using [Symbol.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/replace) well-known symbol.

> The Symbol.replace well-known symbol specifies the method that
>   replaces matched substrings of a string. This function is called by
>   the String.prototype.replace() method.

```js
const string = 'hello world hello world hello world hello';

class ReplaceButFirst {
     constructor(word, replace = '') {
         this.count = 0;
         this.replace = replace;
         this.pattern = new RegExp(word, 'g');
     }
     
     [Symbol.replace](str) {
          return str.replace(this.pattern, m => !this.count++ ? m : this.replace);
     }
}

console.log(
  string.replace(new ReplaceButFirst('world'))
);
```

Comment: This is also a very slick answer! Probs better for a Node script than a browser script.

Answer (score 1):

In my solution, I am replacing first occurrence with a current timestamp, then replacing all occurrences and then finally replacing timestamp with `world`

You can also use `str.split('world')` and then join

```
var str = 'hello world hello world hello world hello';
var strs = str.split('world');
str = strs[0] + 'world' + strs.slice(1).join('');
console.log(str);
```

```js
var str = 'hello world hello world hello world hello';

const d = Date.now()
str = str.replace('world', d).replace(/world/gi, '').replace(d, 'world');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: what happens if the timestamp itself a word in that sentence?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = 'hello world hello world hello world hello'; 

var count = 0;
var result = str.replace(/world/gi, function (x) {
  if(count == 0) {
      count++;
      return x;
    } else {
      return ''; 
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. Get the substring up until and including the first occurrence.
2. Append to that the substring after the first occurrence, with all other occurrences removed:

```js
    function replaceExceptFirst(str, search) {
         let index = str.indexOf(search);
         return str.substring(0, index + search.length) + 
             str.substring(index + search.length).replace(/world/g, '')
    }
    
    console.log(replaceExceptFirst('hello world hello world world hello', 'world'))
```