# Jest: TypeError: replaceAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

[`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) is a useful method and while building and executing everything works fine. However, all Jest-tests fail with the following error:

```
TypeError: replaceAll is not a function
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.6.5",
  "vue": "^2.6.11",
  "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
  "vue-i18n": "^8.22.0",
  "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
  "vue-router": "^3.3.4",
  "vuex": "^3.5.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.0",
  "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
  "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
  "typescript": "~3.9.3",
  "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## The problem

This happens because `replaceAll` is a new function not implemented in all browsers nor older Node.js versions (older than 15.0), as mentioned in the other answer. You can see which browsers support it in [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replaceall):

[image]

But, instead o using `.replace` with a RegExp, you can add a polyfill to support older browsers (if needed). In my case, I'm using Electron, so I need to do it for Jest only.

The shim can be [found here](https://github.com/es-shims/String.prototype.replaceAll).

## The solution

### Using as a polyfill for browsers

1. Install as a dependency with `npm i string.prototype.replaceall` or `yarn add string.prototype.replaceall`;
2. Add the following code in your project. It need to be added in one place only.

```js
import replaceAllInserter from 'string.prototype.replaceall';

replaceAllInserter.shim();
```

### Using in Jest only

#### Update Node.js

As @leonheess mentioned in the comments, you can update Node.js to a more recent version. You'll need a version that uses the [version 8.5 from V8](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-85), which is when `.replaceAll` was implemented.

According to the [list available on the Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), neither version uses V8 8.5, but as of Node.js 15.0.0, the version 8.6 of V8 is used. So, upgrade to Node.js v15 or higher.

#### Use as a polyfill

If you want to fix this problem for Jest only, you can do as mentioned [in this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/797#issuecomment-843175877):

1. Install as a dev dependency with `npm i -D string.prototype.replaceall` or `yarn add -D string.prototype.replaceall`;
2. Modify your Jest config, add a `setupFilesAfterEnv` property as bellow:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"]
  }
}
```

3. Add the following code to your `jestSetup` file:

```js
import replaceAllInserter from 'string.prototype.replaceall';

replaceAllInserter.shim();
```

Comment: For Jest only, the polyfill solution worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 62):

This most likely happens because `String.prototype.replaceAll` is not implemented in Node.js (at least as of version `v14.15.0`).

One alternative you could use are regular expressions like in this example:

```js
const str = 'foo-foo';
const regex = /foo/g; // Note the 'g' flag, which matches all occurrences of the expression

console.log(str.replace(regex, 'bar')); // 'bar-bar'
```

You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more info on regular expressions.

Comment: And if you need to pass some random string. Maybe html tag with attributes. Then this becomes even bigger issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add this anywhere in your main.js file

```
if (typeof String.prototype.replaceAll === "undefined") {
  String.prototype.replaceAll = function (match, replace) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(match, 'g'), () => replace);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work if the `match` is an actual regex like `.`, but I combined your answer with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340174/4759619)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Babel for transpiling your code (to ES5) and also allow it to inject polyfills where needed.

In your case, using `.replaceAll` method fails because, as explained in other answers, the tests are running on a Node version which does not support that method.

I do not advice doing that the other answerers say, because they are simply fixing this **specific** problem, but you might ran into similar problems if you'll use other methods not supported by your current Node version.

To guarantee never to have such problems, *Babel* is used alongside [`core-js`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#corejs).

Here's an important quote from this page:
https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel

> `babel-jest` is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project.

You would also need to install a Babel preset for `vue` so it would compile you vue-specific files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/babel-preset-app

So, in your root folder, look for the *Babel* configuration file, or create one: `babel.config.js` (used to be `.babelrc.js` or a `.json` file).

Use this configuration:

1. make sure to update your `core-js` package and explicitly mention the minor version when configuring it for Babel (see below)
2. must activate the `useBuiltIns` setting in `@babel/preset-env` for core-js polyfills to work.
3. the `targets` setting should also be specified, since your tests run on Node (and not your browser). You can also set up a `.browserlist` file for that.

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { 
      "corejs": "3.26", 
      "useBuiltIns": "usage", 
      "targets": { "node": "current" } 
    }],
    '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
};
```

---

Interesting Read:

[Running Mocha 6 ES6 tests with Babel 7, how to set up?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74913882/104380)

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you're using an old version of node.js.
Me, I forgot I'm using Node Version Manager or NVM.
A couple of days ago I switched to version 14.19.1 for another project. So, now I have to switch back to 18.18.2 by keying `$ nvm use 18.18.2`.